# Is it possible to exclude a depot subdirectory from "get latest revision" on a higher level directory in Perforce/P4V?

Tags: perforce, p4v

Using the P4V Perforce client, we regularly need to get the latest revision of a directory with hundreds of subdirectories of files, but recently a few files have been added which are extremely large compared to all the others.  When selecting "get latest revision" of the higher level directory, these larger files will easily all available disk space  before throwing errors.

Is it possible to exclude those files/subdirectories when "get latest revision" is run by people who don't need them, without interfering with anyone who *does* need them?

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t need those files, the best option is to exclude them from your client view.  If you’re using streams, do this by creating a virtual stream.

I might also suggest moving the big files into a sibling directory to make it easier to avoid them —- while Perforce’s client view management features make it possible to customize your view at a very fine grained level, complex client views are often a “smell” that the depot isn’t organized well.  In general files that always need to be synced together should be close together in the namespace, and files that often need to be excluded should be in their own isolated section of the namespace (ie a top level directory than can easily be avoided or mapped out as a single unit).